# in flutter, when building an APK, where the unused installed packages go, does it be included even if we don't use it in the app or it will be removed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

so I just go wondering, because sometimes it happens, when we install a package to the flutter project, after a while, we just don't use it anymore, when building the app, is it be included in the APK files, or flutter framework remove it and it doesn't use it, and should I delete the unused packages files or it doesn't matter if I leave it

thanks for reading

Comment: A non-debug build will be "tree-shaken", meaning all unreachable code will simply not be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone is confused with this topic, I know its answer now.

so by reference to this article from the official flutter framework website, [Shrinking your code with R8](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#shrinking-your-code-with-r8)

> R8 is the new code shrinker from Google, and it’s enabled by default when you build a release APK or AAB. To disable R8, pass the --no-shrink flag to flutter build apk or flutter build appbundle.

the R8 code shrinker is by default enabled on building the releases of your app, and that R8 code shrinker handles something called tree shaking, which removes any code that you're not using in the whole project

read also :

[Shrink, obfuscate, and optimize your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)